# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (what is it supposed to instead?)

Tags: javascript

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

I am trying to pass in an array of objects. I am getting this error for the line in bold below. I am not sure what it is supposed to be instead of 0 since it is the beginning of the array.

**question: `${questionData.results[0].question}`,**

```
const questions = [
    {
        question: `${questionData.results[0].question}`,
        answers: [
            `${questionData.results[0].correct_answer }` === true ,
            `${questionData.results[0].incorrect_answers[0] }` === false,
            `${questionData.results[0].incorrect_answers[1] }` === false,
            `${questionData.results[0].incorrect_answers[2] }` === false
        ]
    }
```

Comment: The error message is clear, `questionData.results` is `undefined`. The question is, why do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: why the string interpolation? why not question : questionData.results[0].question

Comment: can you post some of the questionData JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

it means `questionData.results` is undefined or empty. so trying to access the first record [0] is not going to be possible.

try adding a `console.log(questionData)` statement to see what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that `questionData` does not contain `results`, so when you try `questionData.result`, it returns `undefined`, instead of the array you are expecting.